# Why does "10" > "9" = false?

Tags: javascript

Is this a failure in JavaScript's attempt to convert them to numbers? If so, what numbers are they being converted to? Or what is the logic behind the string 10 being less than the string 9?

Comment: For the same reason that "alpha" > "beta" = false

Answer (score 12):

It's comparing the strings "alphabetically", and 1 comes before 9 in the character "alphabet".

Comment: @Ragnar You'll notice I was the one who closed the question.

Comment: I won't be arogant so +1 for you.