# Why is 10 less than 9?

Tags: javascript

I have a function `switcher()` which has an Object argument, `video`. It should log `'Start'` if `video.start <= video.ende`. It's working fine in most cases (example: `video.start = 1` and `video.ende = 3`), but when `video.start = 9` and `video.ende = 10` it logs `'End'`.

```js
function switcher(video)   
{
    console.log("Start: " + video.start);
    console.log("End: " + video.ende);

    if(video.start <= video.ende) // Not working correctly
    {
        console.log("Start");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("End");
    }
}
```

`console.log()` successes:

```
console.log: addon: Start: 1
console.log: addon: End: 3
console.log: addon: Start
```

`console.log()` Failed:

```
console.log: addon: Start: 9
console.log: addon: End: 10
console.log: addon: End
```

Why is it so?
How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript string/integer comparisons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630123/javascript-string-integer-comparisons)

Comment: Additional duplicate targets: [Why does “10” > “9” = false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025586/why-does-10-9-false) and [Why is one string greater than the other when comparing strings in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087811/why-is-one-string-greater-than-the-other-when-comparing-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `video.start` and `video.ende` are strings, not numbers, so they're being compared lexicographically, not numerically. Convert them to numbers before comparing.

```
if (Number(video.start) <= Number(video.ende))
```

Or you can fix the code that creates the `video` object so it converts to a number at that time.